# To create a bmi calculator on my website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to create a bmi calculator as a project .But since i am a beginner i have been coding for days without any actual success.I would like to add this calculator to my site [Lifestyle](https://fitterlives.blogspot.com/).It would be very helpful if anyone could help me some java script coding support.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
<table cellpadding="10px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Weight:</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtWeight" placeholder="Weight (kg)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Height:</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtHeight" placeholder="Height (cm)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateBMI()" /> <br />

<span>Your Body Mass Index: </span>
<span id="lblBMI"></span>

<script>
    function calculateBMI() {
            var weight = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtWeight').value);
            var height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtHeight').value / 100);
            var BMI = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2) * 10) / 10;

            document.getElementById('lblBMI').value = BMI;
    }
</script>
```